# WebRTC doesn't work with AudioContext

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am making audio chat website using WebRTC. I have one problem.

When receiving remote audio from peer. This doesn't work (I can't hear any audio)

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(e.stream);
audioStream.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

While this works

```
var audio2 = document.querySelector('audio#audio2');
audio2.srcObject = e.stream;
```

The reason I need to do it is because I need to be able to control the audio (effects, volume), and as I know, AudioContext provides that. But for some reason, it doesn't work. 
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe "doesn't work"?

Comment: I can't hear any audio.

Comment: Use `.createMediaStreamDestination()`

Comment: var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
var audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(e.stream);
audioStream.connect(destination);             Doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.createMediaStreamSource()` with `.createGain()`

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var source = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = .5; 
source.connect(gainNode);
source.connect(ctx.destination);
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tkw13bfg/2

Alternatively, create an `AudioNode`, use `.createGain()`

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var audio = new Audio();
audio.srcObject = stream;
var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = .5;   
audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  var source = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(audio.srcObject);
  audio.play();
  audio.muted = true;
  source.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
}
```

Comment: .start() throws an error : `start is not a function`. When used on audioStream

Comment: related to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121673#c96

Comment: note - on Google Chrome, it's really important to assign a value to audio.srcObject, and then read from it again later with createMediaStreamSource, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Only the second snippet of code worked for me (on Chrome 100.0.4896.60). Setting `mute` to true is key here (e.g. setting volume to 0 does *not* work).