# No audio from WebRCT stream on chrome without audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webrtc, sip

I have web application to make audio calls between clients. As server I use FreeSwitch with SIP (using SIP.js) through secure web socket. When I make call between firefox and firefox everything works fine, but when I make call between firefox and chrome I do not hear anything on chrome client. On firefox client I can hear what was send from chrome.

Using Wireshark I found that stream reach client machine and is correct. After long trial and error I found that creating `audio` tag in js code and assigning remote stream to it as `srcObject` helps (adapting solution from [WebRTC doesn't work with AudioContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784137/webrtc-doesnt-work-with-audiocontext)).

```
const audioContext = (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext || window.oAudioContext || window.msAudioContext);

var aaaudio = new Audio();                                           <--- adding those lines helps
aaaudio.srcObject = sipSession.mediaHandler.getRemoteStreams()[0];   <--- adding those lines helps

audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(sipSession.mediaHandler.getRemoteStreams()[0])
var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = .5; 
source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
```

I really don't know why this is not working without audio tag and how can I fix it to work without it. Am I missing something?

Is there any mechanism in Chrome that blocked audio output from stream connected in js without creating explicit new audio tag?

Info: Chrome was started both with disabled and enabled cors policies