# Workaround implementation: WebRTC missing audiotrack in chromium

Tags: reactjs, audio, webrtc

I'm attempting to setup a local streaming solution using [Project Lightspeed](https://github.com/GRVYDEV/Project-Lightspeed/blob/main/frontend/src/components/VideoPlayer.jsx).
I would ask there, unfortunately the project is basically dead :/

**In short:** When streaming video using `WebRTC`, I get no audio using chromium based browsers but it does work using Firefox.
This appears to be a documented and ongoing issue and I have found the following workarounds:

[41784137](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784137/webrtc-doesnt-work-with-audiocontext)
[24287054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287054/chrome-wont-play-webaudio-getusermedia-via-webrtc-peer-js/55644983#55644983)

Sadly I'm not a dev and have basically no experience with react.. I attempted to implement these workarounds, but to no avail.

##### This is the original code from VideoPlayer.jsx:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { VideoPosterURL } from "../assets/constants";
import { Video } from "../styles/videoPlayerStyles";

const VideoPlayer = ({ src }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (src) {
      videoRef.current.srcObject = src;
      videoRef.current.play();
    }
  }, [src]);

  return (
    <Video
      ref={videoRef}
      playsInline
      autoPlay
      controls
      muted
      poster={VideoPosterURL}
    ></Video>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;

VideoPlayer.propTypes = {
  src: PropTypes.object,
};
```

##### I attempted to implement a workaround:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { VideoPosterURL } from "../assets/constants";
import { Video } from "../styles/videoPlayerStyles";

const VideoPlayer = ({ src }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const audioContextRef = useRef(new AudioContext());
  const audio = new Audio();
  audio.srcObject = src;
  const gainNodeRef = useRef(audioContextRef.current.createGain());

  useEffect(() => {
    if (src) {
      const video = videoRef.current;
      video.srcObject = src;

          audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
                  var source = audioContextRef.current.createMediaStreamSource(audio.srcObject);
                  const gainNode = gainNodeRef.current;
                  gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;
                  audio.play();
                  audio.muted = true;
                  source.connect(gainNode);
                  gainNode.connect(audioContextRef.current.destination);
          }

      video.play();
    }
  }, [src]);

  return (
    <>
      <Video
        ref={videoRef}
        playsInline
        autoPlay
        controls
        muted
        poster={VideoPosterURL}
      ></Video>
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;

VideoPlayer.propTypes = {
  src: PropTypes.object,
};
```

##### And attempted to implement another workaround this way: (same concept)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { VideoPosterURL } from "../assets/constants";
import { Video } from "../styles/videoPlayerStyles";

const VideoPlayer = ({ src }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (src) {
      videoRef.current.srcObject = src;
      videoRef.current.play();
      
      const audioElement = new Audio();
      audioElement.muted = true;
      audioElement.srcObject = src;

      const checkAudioTrack = () => {
        if (audioElement.srcObject && audioElement.srcObject.getAudioTracks().length > 0) {
          const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
          const audioStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioElement.srcObject);
          audioStream.connect(audioContext.destination);
          audioElement.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', checkAudioTrack);
        } else {
          console.error("No audio tracks found in the MediaStream.");
          setTimeout(checkAudioTrack, 1000);
        }
      };

      audioElement.addEventListener('canplaythrough', checkAudioTrack);
    }
  }, [src]);

  return (
    <Video
      ref={videoRef}
      playsInline
      autoPlay
      controls
      muted
      poster={VideoPosterURL}
    ></Video>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;

VideoPlayer.propTypes = {
  src: PropTypes.object,
};
```